# Not saving html interactive file with R

Tags: html, r, htmlwidgets

I am trying to design a circos plot using `BioCircos` R package. BioCircos allows to save the plots as .html interactive files. However, when I run the package using RScript the saved .html file is empty. To save the .html file I used saveWidget option from `htmlwidgets` package. Is it something wrong with saveWidget option? The code I used follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
######R script for BioCircos test
library(htmlwidgets)
library(BioCircos)
genomes <- list("chra1" = 217471166, "chra2" = 181034961, "chra3" = 153873357, "chra4" = 153961319, "chra5" = 164033575,
    "chra6" = 154486312, "chra7" = 133565930, "chra8" = 147241510, "chra9" = 91218944, "chra10" = 52432566, "chrb1" = 843366180, "chrb2" = 842558404, "chrb3" = 707956555, "chrb4" = 635713434, "chrb5" = 567300182,
    "chrb6" = 439630435, "chrb7" = 236595445, "chrb8" = 231667822, "chrb9" = 230778867, "chrb10" = 151572763, "chrb11" = 103205957) # custom genome
links_chromosomes_01 <- c("chra1", "chra2", "chra3", "chra4", "chra4", "chra5", "chra6", "chra7", "chra7", "chra8", "chra8", "chra9", "chra10") # Chromosomes on which the links should start
links_chromosomes_02 <- c("chrb2", "chrb3", "chrb1", "chrb9", "chrb10", "chrb4", "chrb5", "chrb6", "chrb1", "chrb8", "chrb3", "chrb7", "chrb6") # Chromosomes on which the links should end
links_pos_01 <- c(115060347, 102611974, 14761160, 128700431, 128681496, 42116205, 58890582, 40356090,
  146935315, 136481944, 157464876, 39323393, 84752508, 136164354,
  99573657, 102580613,
  111139346, 120764772, 90748238, 122164776,
  44933176, 18823342,
  48771409, 128288229, 150613881, 18509106, 123913217, 51237349,
  34237851, 53357604, 78270031,
  25306417, 25320614,
  94266153,
  41447919, 28810876, 2802465,
  45583472,
  81968637, 27858237, 17263637,
  30569409) ### links chra chromosomes
links_pos_02 <- c(410543481, 463189512, 825903588, 353914638, 354135472, 717707494, 643107332, 724899652,
  583713545, 558756961, 642015290, 154999098, 340216235, 557731577,
  643350872, 655077847,
  85356666, 157889318, 226411560, 161566470,
  109857786, 25338955,
  473876792, 124495704, 46258030, 572314729, 141584107, 426419779,
  531245660, 220131772, 353941099,
  62422773, 62387030,
  116923325,
  76544045, 33452274, 7942164,
  642047816,
  215981114, 39278129, 23302654,
  418922633) ### links chrb chromosomes
links_labels <- c("aldh1a3", "amh", "cyp26b1", "dmrt1", "dmrt3", "fgf20", "hhip", "srd5a3",
  "amhr2", "dhh", "fgf9", "nr0b1", "rspo1", "wnt1",
  "aldh1a2", "cyp19a1",
  "lhx9", "pdgfb", "ptch2", "sox10",
  "cbln1", "wt1",
  "esr1", "foxl2", "gata4", "lrpprc", "serpine2", "srd5a2",
  "asns", "ctnnb1", "srd5a1",
  "cyp26a1", "cyp26c1",
  "wnt4",
  "ar", "nr5a1", "ptgds",
  "fgf16",
  "cxcr4", "pdgfa", "sox8",
  "sox9")
tracklist <- BioCircosLinkTrack('myLinkTrack', links_chromosomes_01, links_pos_01,
  links_pos_01, links_chromosomes_02, links_pos_02, links_pos_02,
  maxRadius = 0.55, labels = links_labels)
#plotting results
plot_chra_chrb <- BioCircos(tracklist, genome = chra_chrb_genomes, genomeFillColor = "RdBu", chrPad = 0.02, displayGenomeBorder = FALSE, genomeLabelTextSize = "10pt", genomeTicksScale = 4e+3,
  elementId = "chra_chrb_comp_plot_test.html")
saveWidget(plot_chra_chrb, "chra_chrb_comp_plot_test.html", selfcontained = F, libdir = "lib")
```

The command line to run this script:
`Rscript /path_to/Circle_plot_test.r`

I tried to use this script in RStudio (without `saveWidget()` command), however it took too long to run in my personnel computer and the results was not displayed. However, this could be due to memory usage setup because when I took off some data, the script easily generates the plot in RStudio and I am able to save it. Is there other way to save the .hmtl interactive files in R or am I doing something wrong using `htmlwidgets` package in my script?
Thanks all in advance for any help and comments.

Answer (score 1):

When you said it took too long to run, that was a sign that something was wrong! You weren't getting anything when you used `saveWidget`, because there is nothing returned from `BioCiros`.

I found two things that are a problem. The first one will result in a blank output—you can't use a '.' in the element ID. This ID will be used in the HTML coding.

You were getting huge delays due to the scale you set for `genomeTickScale`. That scaling value is for a tick mark attribute. I'm not sure why you set it to .004. However, when I comment out that line, it renders immediately. I have no issues with saving the widget, either.

--One other thing, you had `chra_chrb_genomes` as the object name assigned to the parameter `genome` in the function `BioCircos`. I assumed it was the object `genome` from your question since it was the only unused object.

[image]

The only things I changed were in the `BioCircos` function:

```
(plot_chra_chrb <- BioCircos(tracklist, genome = genomes,   #chra_chrb_genomes, 
                            genomeFillColor = "RdBu", 
                            chrPad = 0.02, 
                            displayGenomeBorder = FALSE, 
                            genomeLabelTextSize = "10pt", 
                            # genomeTicksScale = 4e+3,              # problematic
                            elementId = "chra_chrb_comp_plot_test"  # no periods
                            ))
```